# Angular2+: How to make parent router-outlet apply to differently to different child components

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-router, router-outlet

In my Angular app, I have a root `app.component` and several child components.
My `app.component.html` simply looks like this:

```
<app-top-navigation></app-top-navigation>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The problem for me is that I want all my subcomponent pages to be surrounded with the `<div class="container-fluid"`, but with an **exception** for the `home.component`. I don't want my `home.component.html` to be constrained the in the box that `.container-fluid` puts it in.

**Is there an Angular way to do this?**

P.S. I know that in my simplified example here I could just apply some special CSS in `home.component` but suppose it was a larger project and there were a few sub-commponents that required this exceptional treatment.

Answer (score 0):

Your home component could be simple as this.
Make sure you have a separate global route set for home.

```
componentRoutes: Routes = [
{
  path: '/home',
  component: HomeComponent
},{
  path: '',
  component: MainComponent
}];
```

You could also keep home path to ' ' if you need to

Home component Template - 
home.html

```
<app-top-navigation></app-top-navigation>

<div class="home" >
    # Home page content
</div>
```